# RewriteMap not working to prevent hotlinking

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hotlinking, rewritemap

I am trying to prevent hot linking of images and adding allowed hosts by RewriteMap in txt file dynamically, but unfortunately the condition is not working.

Here is code of VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot D:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\base
    ServerName base.test.dev
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteMap allowedhosts "txt:D:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\base/rules.txt"
</VirtualHost>
```

and following is htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^${allowedhosts:$1} [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png)$ - [F]
```

and following is txt file line for host to allow to access images

```
http(s)?://(www\.)?base.test.dev
```

Please someone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: it is blocking images for every one

Answer (score 0):

From [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)

> **txt**
>
> A plain text file containing space-separated key-value pairs, one per line.

The problem seems to be the key part, which is the captured image type, e.g. one of `gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png`.

---

You might give the referrer as a key and employ a default value for unknown/invalid hosts

```
RewriteCond ${allowedhosts:%{HTTP_REFERER}|NOT_ALLOWED} NOT_ALLOWED
RewriteRule \.(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png)$ - [F]
```

This would work as follows: the `HTTP_REFERER` is looked up in the map. If it is not found in the map, the default value `NOT_ALLOWED` is returned, and the condition will be true. In this case, a `403 Forbidden` will be returned.

Comment: Thank for your reply, the solution without map file works fine, but I need the solution with map file because there are hundreds of hosts and I need to build that file dynamically, that's why i keep that separate from htaccess file. I have tried the Key Values solution for map file, but it does not work.

Comment: Ok, but you cannot have multiple hosts for one key (gif, jpg, etc.).